# GrandPermissionRule doesn't work after extending AndroidJUnitRunner

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, androidx-test

After extending `AndroidJUnitRunner` `GrandPermissionRule` stopped working and the test is blocked by permission dialog.

Here is my runner class:

```
package com.my.package

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
import com.my.package.TestApplication

class MockTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    @Throws(
        InstantiationException::class,
        IllegalAccessException::class,
        ClassNotFoundException::class
    )
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

Gradle runner config:

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'com.my.package.MockTestRunner'
```

Before everything was working as intended.
Anyone had this issue? How to fix that?